# Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml are ignored in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

In my Flutter application I need to use microphone. As I test application in emulator in `myproject/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml` I have:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="temp.myproject.myproject">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
</manifest>
```

However, my application still doesn't have permission to use microphone. So, I need to use `permission_handler` library to make it work:

```
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [Permission.microphone].request();
```

I thought that adding `uses-permission..` in AndroidManifest is enough, but it doesn't work without `permission_handler`. Could anyone explain why, or what I do/understand wrong.

Comment: Adding a permission request in manifest is not enough for nearly all permissions. At runtime you have to ask the user to confirm the permission request. Or the user has to go to the settings for your app and allow the permission there..

Comment: @blackapps I removed `uses_permission..` from `AndroidManifest`. It works as before with `permission_hander`. So, what is the point of adding `uses_permission..` in `AndroidManifest`?

Comment: There are some permissions in Android which are need to be asked to the user and just adding them in the Manifest file is not enough. And microphone permission is one of them

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the app and install it again on your physical or emulator device, in order make sure that the app is running from fresh install, and to make sure that the `AndroidManifest` is re-register into the device